# How would I show a "loading" screen when there's a very large amount of changes to the UI due to a state change?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So I have a prototype app that has a "dark mode" and "localization" toggle (I know bad UX just doing it for the prototype)

[image]

Now when I change modes there's obviously going to be a lag before the state propagates down to the components, but I was wondering... how would I make it so that there's a "BlurView" that would blur the screen while the transition to the new state is happening and get removed once the state transition has completed.

I am presuming it's some sort of `useEffect` type hook.

Comment: We can consider useTransition ? https://react.dev/reference/react/useTransition

Comment: I've never heard of this one before @kag how would it be used?

Comment: I looked into useTransition, it doesn't seem to work as I would expect on React Native, likely my test is wrong but the pending state never switches to true.  I can't use timeout so I had to do the while loop thing as well.

Comment: @kag I don't think useTransition can work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77693273/using-usetransition-in-react-native but supposedly it will make the UI less `janky` though I can't get it to show `true` in pending

Answer (score 1):

A "loader" or "progress bar" or "blurred screen" or whatever effect you decide to show is mainly driven by a single state variable.

For consistency sake, I always call this variable

```js
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
```

When `loading` is true, then my component renders some type of indication that activity is ongoing, such as using an MUI `<CircularProgress>` or `<LinearProgress>`, or even just `<div>Loading...</div>`.

You can do it such that your component only returns a loading indicator, or it returns its other UI:

```js
if (loading) {
  return <div>Loading...</div>;
} else {
  return (<div>My main Component Output Goes Here</div>);
}
```

or you might put it into your components main output:

```js
return (
  <div>
    Main Component Output Is Here
    {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
  </div>
);
```

When you invoke the action that is "going to take a long time" (this hopefully is an asynchronous action), then you start by `setLoading(true)`, you wrap your asynchronous behaviour with a try/catch/finally, and put in the finally block `setLoading(false)`.  Frequently you kick off these "long time actions" either via a `useEffect()` [base on change of value in a state variable] or an `onClick()` [a user action].

React & JavaScript take care of the rest for you.

Comment: this won't work because the state change I am doing is synchronous via redux or a simple setState as such loading will never be `true` because if I setLoading(true);otherSyncFunctions();setLoading(false), it will resolve to loading = false and will never be true

Comment: You didn't mention that the long running process is synchronous.  But the fact that it is...why not simply wrap that code in a Promise?  Make that code asynchronous.